# How can one get a java.time DateTime using clojure.java-time from #inst Date literal?

Tags: clojure, java-time

Using [clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time) it is possible to parse an #inst Date literal like so:

```
(require '[clj-time.coerce :as c])
(c/from-date #inst "2012-12-12")
;; => #object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0x4a251269 "2012-12-12T00:00:00.000Z"]
```

How would this be done using the new java.time wrapper [clojure.java-time](https://github.com/dm3/clojure.java-time)?

Comment: Do you mean LocalDateTime?  DateTime is from joda.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**PLEASE NOTE: Joda Time and the `clj-time` library which wraps it are both deprecated.** You should use `java.time` via Java interop for most tasks.  There are also [some helper functions here](https://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.java-time.html) you may find useful.

---

Clojure converts each `#inst` literal into a `java.util.Date` object.  All you need is the built-in `.toInstant()` method:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:import [java.time ZonedDateTime ZoneId]))

(defn inst->date-time
  "Convert a java.time.Instant to a DateTime for the supplied ZoneId"
  [inst zoneid]
  (.toLocalDate zdt-utc
    (ZonedDateTime/ofInstant instant zoneid)))
    
(dotest
  (let [may-4    #inst "2018-05-04T01:23:45.678-00:00" ; a java.util.Date
        instant  (.toInstant may-4) ]
    (spyxx may-4)
    (spyx instant)
    (println "utc =>" (inst->date-time instant (ZoneId/of "UTC")))
    (println "nyc =>" (inst->date-time instant (ZoneId/of "America/New_York")))
    ))
```

with result

```
may-4    => <#java.util.Date #inst "2018-05-04T01:23:45.678-00:00">
instant  => #object[java.time.Instant 0x2207eb9f "2018-05-04T01:23:45.678Z"]
utc      => #object[java.time.LocalDate 0x62b5a16f 2018-05-04]
nyc      => #object[java.time.LocalDate 0x379b6a27 2018-05-03]
```

This extension to `j.u.Date` was added to Java at the same time as the `java.time` package exactly to facilitate transition of code away from  `java.util.Date` to `java.time`.

Note that you still have to be careful, as the sample instant yields two different `LocalDate` objects, depending on the time zone used.

---

If you are working with the `java.time` package, you may be interested in [some helper functions](https://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.java-time.html) I wrote.   [The unit tests](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/clj/tst/tupelo/java_time.clj) give good examples of both the helper functions and interop with native `java.time` functions.

If you are looking for a function there and don't find it, there is a good chance that it already exists in the `java.time` package, and is easy to use directly via Java interop.  `java.time` is a very well thought out library (by the author of the previous `Joda Time` library).  Most features of `java.time` are simple & easy to use from Clojure, and do not benefit from having a wrapper function.